# Elastic Net Regression (Prostate Data)

Tags: r, glmnet, mse

In the original Elastic net paper, Zou and Hastie, (2005) examined prostate cancer data for comparison purposes. I would like to regenerate the results using `glmnet` package in `R`. As mentioned in the paper, the response is `lpsa`. The training and test sets are given by the variable `train` in the data. I assumed `alpha = 0.26` (as in the paper) and used cross validation to estimate `lambda`. But I could not get a similar mean squared error to the one given in the paper (which is 0.381). Where is my mistake?

The code I used is given below.

```
library(ElemStatLearn)
library(glmnet)
x  = model.matrix(lpsa ~ .-train, data = prostate)[, -1]
y = prostate$lpsa
#
trainlab = which(prostate$train=="TRUE")
testlab = which(prostate$train=="FALSE")
y.test = y[testlab]

alph=0.26
en.mod = glmnet(x[trainlab, ], y[trainlab], alpha = alph)

set.seed(1)
cv.out = cv.glmnet(x[trainlab, ], y[trainlab], alpha = alph)
bestlambda=cv.out$lambda.min
en.pred = predict(en.mod, s=bestlambda, newx = x[testlab, ])
MSE.en = mean((en.pred-y.test)^2)
MSE.en
[1] 0.5043356
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/B67.2%20(2005)%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf), they used an algorithm called LARS-EN, so you might be interested to check in the package called `elasticnet`, as it implements that algorithm.